# Motorola LI4278 Beep On <BEL>

Tags: java

I have a Motorola LI4278 Bluetooth Scanner which I have connected to a tablet via Bluetooth.  The scanner is setup as a Serial Slave.  I can connect and read the data fine.

However, I would like to implement some sort of feedback to the user incase a scanned serial number is invalid.  According to the LI4278 documentation:

https://docs.symbol.com/manuals/15183402a.pdf page 164

If I send the  character, then the scanner is suppose to make a beeping noise as feedback.

I've enabled the setting on the scanner and tried various options sending the data to the scanner but I cannot get it to work.

Has anyone else seen this issue?  Not sure if the scanner isnt accepting the command or if I am sending wrong data to the serial port...

Here is the code I've tried:

```
byte[] bell = new byte[1];
bell[0] = 7;

OutputStream out = mBtSocket.getOutputStream();
out.write(bell, 0, 1);
out.flush();
```

I've also tried the following:

```
out.write((char)7);
out.flush();
```

If anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you connect over RS-232 and try sending BEL that way? It shows up under the RS-232 only section, which makes me wonder if it might not work over Bluetooth. Also, is it in Point-to-Point mode?

Comment: Yes it is point to point mode.  According to the documentation:

"SPP - the linear imager scanner connects to the PC/host via Bluetooth and performs like there’s a serial connection."

So I figured it should work.  I can test to see if I can make the cradle act like a Serial Port and send through the PC.

Comment: Hmm... I'd try checking that anyway, just to try and narrow down the cause. If it doesn't work serially, you know it's either in the wrong mode or the code is wrong. From there you can try an outside program that lets you send data over RS-232 to check if sending BEL works (setup with the RS-232 params for your scanner - check page 151 for the defaults).

Comment: I contacted Motorola Support and it turns out the <BEL> feather will only work with the use of the CR0078-PC1F007WR (Presentation Base).

Answer (score 0):

Please look at https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/li4278-product-reference-guide-a-en-us.pdf page 7-16.

You must set "Beep On  Character (Enable)" to "enable".

After this it will be work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's also an "Ignore Beep" setting, which I guess you'd want to disable. Not that doing so fixed the issue for us, but it might do so for you.